# file upload using WPF client

Tags: file-upload

I have a WPF client application. Through which I want to upload a file to my web server.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

[WebClient.UploadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile%28VS.71%29.aspx) is the way to go in your case. Sample code is provided in the MSDN article (both for C# and VB.NET).